# Visual Studio 2013 Web Deploy Missing Dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I have recently run into an issue where (for some reason this behaviour has appeared out of nowhere) during web deployment of a project to Azure Websites - some reference assemblies of the dependent projects are not automatically included into the deployment package.

SO this is a rough structure of my project:
1) ASP.NET MVC project that references class library project
2) Class library project that references some NuGet packages

Now, when I web deploy the ASP.NET MVC project to Azure Website - not all of the NuGet packaged assemblies from the reference class library are deployed (it seems that some are included automatically and others are not). Everything works fine when run locally. All of the required assemblies are copied over to the bin folder of the ASP.NET MVC project.

Now, the only way that I have found to work around this issue is to add the NuGet package  of the missing reference directly to ASP.NET MVC project. I really don't like this workaround - since it breaks the modular structure of my project.

Surely there must be a way to specify which assemblies are to be included with Web Deploy? I have tried some pretty extensive google searches on the topic - but that didn't yield an working solution.

Comment: Have you checked that the offending references have "Copy Local" set to true?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - yes, I have done that. All set to "Copy Local".

Answer (score 1):

Try the following for each of the offending Nuget packages:

1. Open the Package Manager Console. Make sure the Default Project dropdown is set to your MVC project.
2. Run `Uninstall-Package [Package Name] -Force`
3. Run `Install-Package [Package Name]`

If you need to keep a particular version of a package instead of just pulling the latest in, you can add `-Version [Version Number]` to the end of the last command.

That will essentially refresh all the references and other bootstrapping for the package, then try to web deploy again.